# How do you make a game to replenish its lives over time?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm using Action Script3 Flash pro cc. I have tried to write codes to my game so that it replenishes the player's lives over time.  But I have had no success. For example, in Candy Crush, it's called 'lives'. You can have maximum of 5 lives. And once you start a level, it takes off 1 life from the 5 lives. And then the timer next to the lives label starts counting down from 20 minutes to 0. once it reaches 0, it gives you 1 life back so that you can start a level again. I tried to do this like this: Frame EventListener to count down from 20 minutes to 0 whenever the number of lives is under 5, and once it reaches 5, stop counting down numbers. It sounds simple and it is simple. But what if the player quits the game while the timer is counting down?? Let's say the player left the game at 3:10pm with 3 lives and 10 min left for a life replenish. And the player starts the game again at 3:30pm. Then the player would have 4 lives and 10 min left for a life replenish. I tried to accomplish this by using date class. But the remaining time gets messed up whenever I quit the game and restart the game.

Comment: Using the Date class will do you no good unless you store the time somewhere on the device, for example in an XML. but this approach has a huge problem: the player could simply set the system time of his device to the appropriate time and get lives instantly. I'm assuming you don't want that, if so the only approach you have is to get the time from the internet and store this in an XML.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do you get the time from the internet?

Comment: sorry, i never did something like this myself. but divillysausages seems to have answered your question already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to keep track of the last time you gave a free life, then just compare the current time with the last time to see how many lives to give.

You'll need to store the `lastFreeLifeTS` timestamp somewhere, so you have 2 options:

- **Locally** - Either a `SharedObject` or an XML file, depending on if you're on, say, the web, or using AIR for a mobile app. As @DodgerThud pointed out, this is easy enough to cheat, either by finding the file and modifying the value, or changing the system time. Candy Crush does this though, so you have to decide if this is an important enough issue for you
- **Online** - Ideally, you would store this timestamp on a server, in which case, it's best to move this logic there as well, so it's the server that decides when you get a free live (either by telling the client, or the client can poll the server when it thinks it should have one)

Getting your timestamp is as simple as:

```
this.lastFreeLifeTS = ( new Date() ).time;
```

Call this when you either a) give a new free life, or b) use a life when you were at maximum (as then you want your next free life to come at the maximum time from that point).

Then you need to deal with 2 issues:

- When the player should get a life in the game
- When the player comes back after X amount of time

The first one is easy - just have a timer counting down (NOTE: you don't need to go once every frame - that's higher fidelity than's needed. Once every second or so is all you need). When your time is up, give the life:

```
var currTime:Number = ( new Date() ).time;
var diff:Number = ( currTime - this.lastFreeLifeTime );
var lifeTime:Number = 1000 * 60 * 20; // give a life every 20 minutes
if( diff > lifeTime )
{
    giveFreeLife();
    this.lastFreeLifeTime += lifeTime;
}
```

Seeing as you know when you're going to give a new life, you could almost replace it with a `getTimer()`, which would mean you don't need to keep creating new `Date` objects all the time.

```
// starting off
var lifeTime:Number = 1000 * 60 * 20; // 20 minutes
var msUntilNextLife:Number = ( ( new Date() ).time - this.lastFreeLifeTime ) + lifeTime;
this.nextFreeLifeTime = getTimer() + msUntilNextLife;

...

// check if we need to give a new life
if( getTimer() > this.nextFreeLifeTime )
{
    giveFreeLife();
    this.lastFreeLifeTime += lifeTime;
    this.nextFreeLifeTime += lifeTime;
}
```

For the second one, you just need to check the timestamp when you start your game, and give any free lives necessary, then you're back to the first type of logic, above.

```
// load our SharedObject/XML and set our lastFreeLifeTime
...

// check how much time has passed and give any lives necessary
var currTime:Number = ( new Date() ).time;
var diff:Number = currTime - this.lastFreeLifeTime;
var lifeTime:Number = 1000 * 60 * 20; // 20 minutes
var numLives:int = int( diff / lifeTime );
if( numLives > 5 )
    numLives = 5; // only give a maximum number of lives
if( numLives > 0 )
{
    giveFreeLives( numLives );

    // update our lastFreeLifeTime only if we didn't give the max number of lives
    // (as otherwise we don't need it)
    // NOTE: because we're adding (lifeTime * numLives), it handles the time between
    // lives nicely. E.g. If we get a life every 20m and we come back after 30m, then
    // our lastFreeLifeTime will be (20 * i), meaning a 10m difference between the 
    // current time, meaning we only have to wait 10m to get our next one
    if( numLives < 5 )
        this.lastFreeLifeTime += lifeTime * numLives;
}
```

**Update - getting time from the internet**

The easiest way to get timestamp from the net it to control the source yourself; i.e. you own the server/webpage that you're asking the timestamp from.

A simple solution is to host the following php code in a file somewhere:

```
<?php
    echo round( microtime( true ) * 1000 );
?>
```

All this does is print the current timestamp to the page. You should be able then read the time using a `URLLoader`:

```
// NOTE: add all the other listeners, like IOErrorEvent, and SecurityErrorEvent
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader( new URLRequest( "http://myserver.com/timestamp.php" ) );
urlLoader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onGetTime );

function onGetTime( e:Event ):void
{
    // remove our event listener so we can clean up
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = ( e.target as URLLoader );
    urlLoader.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onGetTime );

    // the data is the timestamp returned by php, as a string, so convert it
    var timestamp:Number = Number( urlLoader.data );
    if ( isNaN( timestamp ) ) 
    {
        trace( "Couldn't get the timestamp from the server! Returned details: " + urlLoader.data );
        timestamp = ( new Date() ).time; // fallback to client
    }

    // do something with the time
}
```

Problems with this approach

- It's slow; you're making a web request every time you need to know the current time. The time you get won't be the actual current time, due to latency. For most cases, this isn't a problem, though
- You need internet connection; if the user's turned theirs off, this won't work
- You may run into security problems and need to host a crossdomain.xml (maybe)
- It's a lot of hassle; it's a lot more awkward than a simple `(new Date()).time`; you now need to host this file somewhere; if your game is successful, your server can get slammed pretty quickly depending on how many players you have and how many times you're calling this

It's up to you to decide whether or not it's worth it. If your game already has a server component, then this generally isn't a problem. I'd advise you to get it working just on the client first, and come back to it if necessary (i.e. you have a ton of players cheating)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm gonna try this tomorrow. I'm using SharedObject to save the quitting time and starting time for my own code. But how do I get the time from the internet instead of date class in order to prevent cheating as DodgerThud said?

Comment: So the first 2 groups of codes are the same thing except the first one uses only date class and the second one uses getDate() as well as date class. So I can choose just one of them?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of getting time from the internet. Also, yes, the first 2 groups of code are functionally the same - one just creates new `Date` objects, while the other uses `getTimer()` (which returns an int). You can choose whichever one floats your boat